# Prison Architect- Prisoners won't leave truck

Tags: prison-architect

I've tried everything I can think of to fix this problem, but I give up now. The delivery place is in the right location, I have no fences, it's not being blocked by anything. The delivery timer will countdown, and then..nothing. They keep driving. I've played for several in game days now, and no luck.

[image: Prison layout]

Now the timer won't even begin.

Answer (score 4):

I can see that your delivery area is not in contact with the road. For the moment, prisoners will only leave their trucks if the delivery area is touching the side of the road, otherwise, they go right trough without stopping.

See the second tip [here](http://devwiki.introversion.co.uk/pa/index.php/Deliveries) (Beta wiki) and the [bug report](http://bugs.introversion.co.uk/view.php?id=13).

Comment: I am assuming anybody involved with the alpha has a username/password for that devwiki link?

Comment: Yup, you need need an account to access the wiki and to play the game, since the download link is on the wiki.

Answer (score -1):

The Delivery Area needs to touch the road at 4 spaces.

Comment: Did you bother to read the above answer? It has already been answered. Your dupe'ing...